# Better way for selecting table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following (simplified) table structure:

```
<table class="form-table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr><--Need to select and add class on this guy based on h3 class "check"-->
<th scope="row">
<h3 class="check">Default Checbox:</h3>
</th>
<td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So i want to select "table row" above the h3 class "check". Table is generated dynamically so i can't just use `:eq()` ,`:gt()` or `:lt()`.

To select this guy i am using this code:

```
$('tbody tr').find('h3.check').parent().addClass('cool');
$('.cool').parent().addClass('until');
```

But the problem is that i am giving an unnecessary class "cool" in order to make a selection.

```
<table class="form-table">
<tbody>    
<tr>
<tr>
<tr class="until"><--Class successfully added but..-->
<th class="cool" scope="row"><--An extra Class in order to select "table row"-->
<h3 class="check">Default Checbox:</h3>
</th>
<td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a better way for doing this (without adding unnecessary Class) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has)

```
$('tbody tr').has('h3.check').addClass('cool');
```

or [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector)

```
$('tbody tr:(h3.check)').addClass('cool');
```

Comment: @PedroEstrada was typing it

Comment: Thank you I knew it was something simple:=) You have made my day. THX.

Comment: The `'tbody'` selector is redundant, since every TR is a child of a TBODY (whether the tags are included in the markup or not).